# Why am I not able to pip install the packages into my virtual environment via a requirement.txt file?

Tags: pip, anaconda, conda, git-bash, requirements.txt

I created these files:

```
README.md  config/  params.yaml       research/  src/
LICENSE     app.py     main.py  requirements.txt  setup.py   template.py
```

for my project using **template.py**. I am using Git Bash to commit the changes to my github repo.

I used `conda create -n textS python=3.8` to create a virtual environment and activated that enviroment using `conda activate textS`.

I tried to use **requirements.txt** file to install packages:

`$ pip install -r requirements.txt`

but nothing happened.

---

I ran the command:

`$ pip install -r requirements.txt -v`

for detailed output and after the line:

`Using pip 23.3 from C:\Users\Divyansh Gupta\.conda\envs\textS\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

was shown, the execution ended and there was no installation of packages/libraries.

---

Below is the content of the **requirements.txt**:

```
transformers
transformers[sentencepiece]
datasets
sacrebleu
rouge_score
py7zr
pandas
nltk
tqdm
PyYAML
matplotlib
torch
notebook
boto3
mypy-boto3-s3
python-box==6.0.2
ensure==1.0.2
fastapi==0.78.0
uvicorn==0.18.3
Jinja2==3.1.2
-e .
```

---

The path printed by `pip install -r requirements.txt -v` is `(C:\Users\Divyansh Gupta\.conda\envs\textS\lib\site-packages\pip)`.

AND

The path printed by `which pip` is  `(/c/Users/Divyansh Gupta/.conda/envs/textS/Scripts/pip)`.

in first the pip is in **"....\textS\lib\site-packages\pip"**
but in second the pip is in **"..../textS/Scripts/pip"**

Is this discrepancy giving any clue?

---

I have confirmed that my **requirements.txt** file is located in the main directory of my project.

---

I have confirmed that my virtual environment is activated, evident by the astric(*).

---

I have confirmed that my **pip** is working fine by explicitly *pip* installing the pandas package without any issues in my virtual environment(textS).

---

I also updated my **conda**.

---

Kindly help me with this problem.
Thank You!

Comment: Are you using WSL? The output examples in your question show a mix of Windows-syle paths (`C:\ `) and WSL style paths (`/c/`). Could it be a lead to finding the root cause of your issue? The interoperability between WSL and Windows proper is good but not perfect. I recommend you retry from scratch by sticking to only one. If you install *conda* in Windows proper then only use Windows. If you install *conda* from WSL, then only use WSL.

Comment: Thank you @sinoroc for your help, but I don't understand, I am only using Git Bash for my project and have not explicitly manipulated paths,
the command: $ which pip
which produced : /c/Users/Divyansh Gupta/.conda/envs/textS/Scripts/pip
and the command: $ conda info --envs

which produced :

# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\ProgramData\anaconda3
textS                 *  C:\Users\Divyansh Gupta\.conda\envs\textS

for both these command what is my roll if one gives address in "/c/" format and other produced in "C:\" format.

Comment: Oh? So it is Git Bash and not WSL. I see. -- What if you only use Windows command line `cmd` to work with Python things (and do the git operations with git-bash)? Have you tried this? I am not familiar with git-bash (I have not used it in a very long time), so it is hard for me to judge if it might play a role here or not, but in any case it might be safer to try to eliminate Git Bash from the equation.